# Flex 4 Mx:tree not updating with tree.refresh() or tree.reset()

Tags: apache-flex, tree

I'm creating a `mx:tree` with Flex 4 and the tree is being populated with an `XMLList` file,  the file is updated from a database and what I'm trying to accomplish is to refresh the tree so that a different icon is shown depending on the state of completion of a course.

The problem is that the tree is not being updated but the `XMLList` file is, so I would really appreciate some help.

By the way, I don't know about Flex.

Here's the code:

```
public static var treeData:XMLList = new XMLList(MyString);

<mx:Tree id="myTree" width="40%" height="100%" labelField="@label" fontSize="14" focusColor="#ff5003"
                     render="renderTree()"
                     iconFunction="tree_iconFunc"
                     showRoot="false"
                     dataProvider="{treeData}"  
                         change="treeChanged(event)" 
                         depthColors="{myDepthColors}"
                         color="#006596" borderColor="#03B4EC"
                         click="SoundExample(String(selectedNode.@lesson)), habilitar()"
                         alternatingItemColors="{myAlternatingRowColors}"

                         />



    public function renderTree():void {
                    trace("Entró a renderTree");
                    initAppB();
                    if (refreshData){

                        myTree.invalidateList();
                        refreshData = false;
                        myTree.openItems = Globals.treeData;

                        myTree.validateNow();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `XMLList` you could use **bindable** collection like `ArrayCollection`.
With it you don't need to invalidate tree manually. It will be updated automatically when `ArrayCollection` changes.

Also I'm not sure what do you mean by "the tree is being populated with an XMLList file, the file is updated from a database". Could you clarify?

To update a tree you have to update `treeData:XMLList`. If you want to replace it another value try the following:

```
[Bindable] //Notice this metadata
public var treeData:XMLList = new XMLList(MyString);
public function updateTreeData():void {
    var text:String = ...; //loading text
    treeData = new XMLList(text);
}
```